# Gedit3 plugins for ipython, htmltidy, zencoding?

Tags: ide

I'm still not happy with any of my HTML and Python editing options on Ubuntu.

It looks like there are a few different python and iPython plugins for gedit but most seem to be for gedit2. Same with Zen Coding and HTML Tidy.

Are there good HTML and Python plugins for gedit3 that folks like?

Comment: For a list of gedit plugins, check out: https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins - alternatively, if you're willing to try payware, I recommend SublimeText or even PyCharm for a full-blown IDE. I'm a Python developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got [ipython-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697125/i-cant-launch-ipython-listener) running and a session saver plugin. I'm not 100% satisfied but it's good enough.

As a bonus, it looks like a lot of [plugins](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins) have finally been ported to gedit3. Whew.